# Is it possible to add table to excel using Spreadsheetgear - C# .NET (excel way is INSERT->Table)

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, spreadsheetgear

Like the title says is it possible?

I need a table in my exported excel sheet that will be used with data validation setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to Excel Tables (i.e., Excel's *Ribbon > Home > Styles > Format as Table...*), these objects are not supported by SpreadsheetGear, so adding such tables would not be supported, either.  For existing workbooks that contain Excel Tables and are opened in SpreadsheetGear, the Tables feature will get dropped upon opening, which is worth noting that, in addition to formatting being dropped, any "[structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)" will be converted to "#REF!" errors.  An alternative to using structured references would be [Defined Names](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64), which are very well supported by SpreadsheetGear.

I work for SpreadsheetGear, and we do keep track of customer requests for things like this.  So you are welcome to contact us directly at support@spreadsheetgear.com if you would like us to add your contact details to this particular feature request, though I cannot say when we might add Tables to our product.